# Processing a proc results inside another proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is an illustration to explain my problem:

There is a stored proc 'subPROC' which takes a merit level - and returns the student Ids who qualify for this merit level(after a complex algorithm).

Now,I have to write a new proc 'superPROC' which takes the merit level, and return the names of the students instead.
To avoid re-writing the logic, I would call the above proc to receive the student IDs.
Thereafter,i feed in these ids to a query to get the corresponding names.

How do I call 'subPROC',receive its output - and feed it in as a comma separated list in the IN clause,as part of my 'superPROC' code.

I would like to avoid creating temp tables if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use a [User Defined Function](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions) which can be called within SPs, functions or even Views.

```
CREATE FUNCTION subPROC(@ID int) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

return 1;
END
```

Your second function would be

```
CREATE FUNCTION superPROC(@ID int) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

return 1 + @ID;
END
```

and you could call

```
select superPROC(5)
```

It sounds to me like you'd just create a [UDF which returns a table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214485%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).